# Send two request (call two functions) in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So for starters, my redux-saga looks like this. When the `GET_AVAILABLE_FUNDS_REQUEST` action is performed, we execute functions called `getAvailableFunds`

```
export default function* dashboardPageSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(GET_AVAILABLE_FUNDS_REQUEST, getAvailableFunds);
}
```

For this action to be successful, I need to receive data from two requests, so I divided it into two separate functions and did it like this:

```
export function* getAvailableFunds() {
  const { availableFunds, accountBalanceHistory } = yield all({
    availableFunds: call(getAmountMoney),
    accountBalanceHistory: call(getAccountBalanceHistory),
  });

  yield put(
    getAvailableFundsSuccessAction(
      availableFunds.amountMoney,
      availableFunds.currencyName,
      accountBalanceHistory,
    ),
  );
}
```

My two functions look like this:

```
export function* getAmountMoney() {
  const { accessToken } = yield select(makeSelectToken());
  const requestURL = api.bills('amountMoney');
  const requestParameters = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
  };

  try {
    const { amountMoney, currencyName } = yield call(
      request,
      requestURL,
      requestParameters,
    );
    return { amountMoney, currencyName };

  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getAvailableFundsErrorAction(error));

    switch (error.statusCode) {
      case 401:
        yield put(push(routes.login.path));
        break;
      default:
        yield put(push(routes.login.path));
        break;
    }
  }
}

export function* getAccountBalanceHistory() {
  const { accessToken } = yield select(makeSelectToken());
  const requestURL = api.bills('accountBalanceHistory');
  const requestParameters = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
  };

  try {
    const { accountBalanceHistory } = yield call(
      request,
      requestURL,
      requestParameters,
    );

    return accountBalanceHistory;
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getAvailableFundsErrorAction(error));

    switch (error.statusCode) {
      case 401:
        yield put(push(routes.login.path));
        break;
      default:
        yield put(push(routes.login.path));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

And it works, but it seems to me that something does not fit here. First of all, my eslint tells me not to use return in generators. Is what I wrote correct at all? Can you write it better?

Comment: why not using `yield` instead of `return`?

Comment: yield does not work. possibly I can do return yield

Comment: returning in a value in a generator is the correct thing to do. also I think you are missing return values if there is an exception in both functions. you'll get undefineds in the getAvailableFundsSuccessAction payload https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: can you send a link to the eslint error that's telling you not to put a return in the end of a generator?